# SQL query to convert date format to another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to convert from `02/03/2012` to `2/3/2012` format in SQL Server

Comment: just to be clear are you trying to remove the leading 0's from the day and month portion of the date?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

I think, this will be helpful...

**EDIT:** (Same Question)

[In SQL Server, how to convert a date to a string in format M/D/YYYY? (no leading zeros, not MM/DD/YYYY)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128558/in-sql-server-how-to-convert-a-date-to-a-string-in-format-m-d-yyyy-no-leading)

Answer (score 1):

if you're running SQL Server 2012, you can do this:

```
SELECT FORMAT ( @your_date_value, 'd', 'en-US' )
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

Answer (score 1):

And for your question answer

```
SELECT Convert(varchar, GETDATE(),1)
```

Comment: At least in sql 2005 this won't drop the leading 0 off the day and month which is what is being asked for

Comment: Hi Greg I think this may help http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx for user

Comment: And i think this question is from SQL SERVER 2008 if i am right

Comment: correct, it is adking about 2008 (I only had 2005 in front of me). Even in 2008 I think format 1 (and 101 and 111 that you suggested previously) will still give you leading zeros on day and month. The question is asking how to remove those zeros

Answer (score 0):

This is going to get your exact results..

```
Declare @test datetime 

Set @test = '02/03/2012'

Print  Convert(VARCHAR(10) , @test,101 )

Print  REPLACE(LEFT(Convert(VARCHAR(10) , @test,101 ),5),0,'') + RIGHT(Convert(VARCHAR(10) , @test,101),5)
```

RESULT:

```
02/03/2012
2/3/2012
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!