# T-SQL Date Format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to convert `19 Dec 2012` to date format returned by getdate() `2012-12-22` .
I need this for date comparison because if I compare **19 Dec 2012** with **19 Nov 2012** , **19 Nov 2012** will turn out to be greater date due to alphabetical comparison.

**EDIT**

I am not database designer for this table , was given table as it is to work on .Otherwise would not have used varchar to store date

Comment: I have a column with entries like 19 Dec 2012 type varchar()..

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! Dates should **always** be stored as `DATE` (or `DATETIME`). If you already have those in your table as `varchar` - convert *that* to a `DATE` or `DATETIME` for comparison - not the other way around!

Comment: SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 106) results in 19 Dec 2012 , isn't there a way to convert the opposite way ..

Comment: just change `varchar` to `date`

Comment: What version of sql server?

Comment: all most the same question where i give my answer 

[Stack overflow Sql Query to Convert date format ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965837/sql-query-to-convert-date-format-to-another/13965919#13965919

Comment: @A.Goutam..Thanks a ton for the link of different date formats..really helpful I have downloaded that page for quick reference in future..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try, *but this returns a string and not a date anymore*

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 106)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7400)

you need to convert it to date first before comparing to `GETDATE`.

```
SELECT convert(date, '19 Dec 2012', 106)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7403)

Are you the one that designed the database? If yes, the next time you design (*or if you have time to alter*) use the appropriate data type.

Comment: `SELECT convert(date, '19 Dec 2012', 106)`

Comment: @MahmoudGamal `120 or 120` has time on it.

Answer (score 6):

Convert both to dates. Don't use string to store date values! Even better, change your database schema and the string mismatch problems go away completely.

Also, please note that Getdate() does not return a string. It returns a date in the datetime data type. The *client* converts that to a string representation.

For more information, go read on "cast and convert" in SQL Server Books Online.

```
Convert (datetime, stringdate1)
```

To fix your broken database column do this:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN BadStringDate datetime;
```